# Python NoneType is not callable when indexing into dict

Tags: python, typeerror

I've come across this strange error that I can't explain.

```
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:05:24) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import UserDict
>>> a = UserDict.UserDict()
>>> b = {}
>>> b[a]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I understand that this should be an error. I don't understand why it says `'NoneType' object is not callable`. As far as I can tell I'm not calling anything in the line that causes the error.

I expected the error would be something more like this:

```
>>> b[b]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Can someone please explain this to me before I go insane?

Comment: `hash(UserDict.UserDict())` produces the same error; obviously there's something in the implementation of UserDict that is doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at `UserDict` implementation as suggested by @Wooble, I see this:

```
__hash__ = None # Avoid Py3k warning
```

Therefore it's true that the problem is because of the implementation of `UserDict`.

If you really need to use your own dictionary type, I suggest to subclass directly from `dict` and implement your own `__hash__` method or, alternatively, transform the dictionary into a hashable object with the help of, for example, `frozenset`:

```
>>> a = UserDict.UserDict()
>>> b[frozenset(a.items())]
```

Comment: (Note that it's almost certainly a bad idea to try to use a dict, even with a UserDict wrapping it, as a hash key)

Comment: @Wooble Yes, you're certainly right. Using a dictionary object as a key isn't usually the way to go.

Comment: Yes, I realise that it's a bad idea. It's just that when I saw the NoneType error it took me a few minutes to find the real problem because the error message made no sense. So I wanted to understand the cause of the obscure error message.

Answer (score 0):

`UserDict.UserDict().__hash__` is `None`. Combine with Wooble's comment and you will see why this happens